# Choose from multiple return values

Tags: powershell, scripting

When I have a function, which uses several `Write-Output` commands and returns single number, how can I get number value in function caller code?
As far as I got, line

```psh
[int] $var = Get-MyNumber(...)
```

gets me the error

> Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type "System.Int32"".

Probably because PowerShell returns an array of objects (containing `Write-Output` messages) back to caller code, where the assignment to the `[int]`-typed variable fails. Got that.

Now, how can I tell PowerShell that I'm interested in only a single value from those returned from the function, which is typed as `[int]`.

BTW, I DON'T want to choose output by indexing the return array as I could mess up the indexes in the return array simply by adding another `Write-Output` line. (Which will happen sooner or later due to code maintenance).

Code

```psh
function f1() {
    Write-Output "Lala"
    return 5
}

[int] $x = f1
Write-Output $x
```

Results in the same error.

Comment: Can you post the code for `Get-MyNumber`?

Comment: Why are you using `Write-Output` multiple times if you don't want to return multiple values? If you are trying to display information to the user, use `Write-Host` (or better yet, use `Write-Verbose`).

Comment: It's not problem of using Write-Output. It's not even problem of preferring it over Write-Host (http://goo.gl/gHEle9 and many more ...). It's just how PowerShell works and I can't seem to be able to get my head around it.

Comment: You do have to be careful in PowerShell to not "accidentally" write something to the output stream, but using Write-Output explicitly is not an accident.    As @briantist says, there are other options to write-host besides write-ouptut (like write-verbose and write-debug)

Comment: So basically ... once I decide to return (for example) number from my function, I can't use Write-Output anymore ...

Comment: @MatthewLowe actually, once you decide to return a value, that is when you *would* use `Write-Output`. You wouldn't really use it otherwise. So the question is what else are you using it for? I could only think of writing output for a user to see, like status messages, and `Write-Output` is the wrong tool for that job.

Comment: Write-Host is nice, it can get the job done when displaying info to user. But I read several articles where they preferred Write-Output over it. One of the reasons was that Write-Host output can't be redirected. And that sucks pretty much for me. Since I'm not using advanced functions, I must set $VerbosePreference variable so I can see verbose messages. But ok.  I'm just frustrated how intuitively this whole PS thing 'works'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see from your edit that you are using `Write-Output` to display a status message.

You should use `Write-Host` for that, or if you were using an [advanced function](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847806.aspx), I would recommend using `Write-Verbose` and calling the function with `-Verbose` when you want to see the messages (see [about_CommonParameters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847884.aspx)).

Updated code:

```powershell
function f1() {
    Write-Host "Lala"
    return 5
}

[int] $x = f1
Write-Host $x
```

### Advanced Function Example

```powershell
function f1 {
[CmdletBinding()]
param()

    Write-Verbose "Lala"
    return 5
}

$x = f1
# The "Lala" message will not be seen.

$x = f1 -Verbose
# The "Lala" message will be seen.
```

### Why `Write-Output` seems to work outside of a function:

`Write-Output` passes the input object to the caller. In the case of code that is executed directly in the host, and not in a function or cmdlet, the caller is the host, and the host decides what to do with it. In the case of powershell.exe (or ISE), it displays it.

`Write-Host` on the other hand, always writes to the host; it doesn't pass anything back to the caller.

Also note that `Write-Output` is, basically, optional. The following lines are equivalent:

```powershell
Write-Output $x
$x
```

Comment: I usually add to your final note that the following are also the same.

`return $x`
and
`$x ;
return`